# Remove index.php from the url with laravel 5

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I checked many posts here about removing index.php from url but I could not get the desired results, I already added my local url site name to virtual hosts file (I use wamp) and when I write url like this it work `http://first-app.com`

My problem when I navigate to another folder like "songs" this url does not work, I get url not found

`http://first-app.com/songs`

while if I used index.php it work

`http://first-app.com/index.php/songs`

here is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<Directory C:\wamp\www\composer-demo\first-app\public>
Order Deny,Allow 
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\composer-demo\first-app\public"
ServerName first-app.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Can that be solved from modifying this file ? or I need to modify .htaccess file located at the public folder ? here it is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this a cms or other software driven test site? It looks like it's got an incomplete set of rewrite rules if that's the case. Each type has different requirements for how you structure the rewrite rules, so it can't really be guessed at without more information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527573/friendly-urls-in-laravel-am-i-doing-it-right apparently laravel doens't use apache rewrite to get its url data, via query string or whatever, so I can't offer any advice. Make sure to post relevant information like that when asking for help, this isn't actually a rewrite question at all, it's a Laravel question.

Comment: @Lizardx it was very clear I am talking about Laravel, did you see the Title and Tags ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need was to enable `rewrite_module` in the apache server then restart, since I use wamp I only selected the module from the list menu